# SharePoint with jQuery disables page scroll or ribbon or clicks

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have following jquery saved in a file and uploaded to asset library. I reference the file in Content Editor web part. Is there any reason why the jquery code would disable ribbon.

```
<script src="http://inside.nov.com/_layouts/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://inside.nov.com/_layouts/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://inside.nov.com/_layouts/jquery/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://inside.nov.com/_layouts/jquery/jquery-ui-themes-1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Hide Text Filter Control
    var controlID = "ctl00_m_g_ae01f1bd_e6a3_4044_8045_ab8b29c41f89_SPTextSlicerValueTextControl";  
    //$("input[id$='"+ controlID +"']").closest("tr").hide();   
    document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3").style.display='none';
    $('#btnSearch').click(moveValue); //this works too
    //$('#btnSearch').on('click', moveValue); //this works too

    var externalParties = [];

    window.onload = function() {
    window.setTimeout(readyCall, 1000);
    }
        function readyCall(){
          var externalParties = [];
          $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            listName: "EmployeeBasicData",
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields> <FieldRef Name='FullName' /> </ViewFields>",
            async: false,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
              $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                externalParties.push($(this).attr("ows_FullName"));
              });
            }
          });

            $("#EmployeeName").autocomplete({
                            source: externalParties,
                            minLength: 3                
              });
        }   
 });    
 //<!--<input type="button" value="OK" id="btnSearch" name="btnSearch" onclick="moveValue()"/>  -->
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function moveValue() {
   var employeeField = document.getElementById("EmployeeName");
   var otherControl = document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_ae01f1bd_e6a3_4044_8045_ab8b29c41f89_SPTextSlicerValueTextControl");
   //Making sure both fields are not undefined before accessing their properties.
   if(employeeField && otherControl){
      otherControl.value = employeeField.value; 
        __doPostBack('<%= btnSearch.UniqueID %>','')
   }else{
     //Use for debugging, delete comment once done
     alert("employeeField: " + employeeField  + ", otherControl: " + otherControl);
   }
}
</script>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="EmployeeName">Employee Name</label>
    <input type="text" size="40" id="EmployeeName"> 
    <input type="button" value="OK" id="btnSearch" name="btnSearch" />  
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Is your script throwing any errors? Any script error on the page is likely to prevent SharePoint from scrolling or responding to Ribbon interaction.

Comment: I added print shot of developer tool. only error I see is "SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited." Should I be looking anywhere else for script error or other errors.

Comment: No, if the script were generating errors, it should show up in the console. I don't see anything obviously wrong about your script; in this case, I think I'd start commenting blocks of it out to narrow down what specifically is causing SharePoint to break. Then we can go from there.

Comment: cbono: I tried that but it did not help.Any other ideas?